# Click Function Firing More Than Expected

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I have an accordion that's hidden until a button is clicked. The accordion is a collection of `li`(each of which contains a `div`) that are created dynamically. Here is what the jQuery code looks like:

```
function accordion() {
    var allPanels = $('#navlist li .panel');
    var id = 0;
    
    allPanels.hide();
    
    $('#navlist li a').on({
        'click' : function(e) {                 
            var selectedPanelID = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');

            jQuery.each($('#navlist li'), function(i, panel) {      
                if(panel.id === selectedPanelID)
                    $(panel).find(".panel").toggle('slow');
                else 
                    $(panel).find(".panel").slideUp('slow');                            
            });             
        }               
    });
}
```

The first time I click the button that shows the accordion everything works fine. However the second time I click the button it seems like this part of the code executes multiple times (the more the button is clicked the more times this code runs. Almost as if the click event is looping):

```
'click' : function(e) {                 
            var selectedPanelID = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');       

            jQuery.each($('#navlist li'), function(i, panel) {      
                if(panel.id === selectedPanelID)
                    $(panel).find(".panel").toggle('slow');
                else 
                    $(panel).find(".panel").slideUp('slow');                            
            });             
        }
```

I thought it was due to event bubbling but it does the same thing even if I add either of the following to the code:
`return false`, `e.preventDefault`, `e.stopPropagation`
Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: i test it a this fiddle and it seems to me to work properly [link](https://jsfiddle.net/srjaaa2t/2/)

Comment: The HTML is created dynamically via JS and the file is too big to include. I can give you a general idea of the HTML structure

Comment: i try to rebuild html by js code. Try to check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srjaaa2t/2/), it seems to work properly.

Comment: Yes that's the general structure of the HTML. I built it just like you did to test on my browser and it works fine. But as soon as I insert it into a larger program I get the issues I've outlined previously.

Comment: It's possible that on click you generate again the same html block without remove the previous? This would generate an error like you described.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a bit more the issue appears to be that the event was bubbling. Using `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` solved the problem although I don't understand why `return false` , `e.preventDefault()`, or `e.stopPropagation()`didn't work. Here is where I add that line of code.

```
'click' : function(e) {                 
        var selectedPanelID = $(this).parent('li').attr('id');       

        jQuery.each($('#navlist li'), function(i, panel) {      
            if(panel.id === selectedPanelID)
                $(panel).find(".panel").toggle('slow');
            else 
                $(panel).find(".panel").slideUp('slow');                            
        }); 
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
    }
```